# Dojo - Dijit.Tree - Updating Tree

Tags: javascript, dojo, javascript-framework

I created a simple tree based on a TreeStoreModel which is backed by ItemFileWriteStore.
I tried updating my tree by deleting and adding items to the store as below, but could not.

```
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dijit.Tree");
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
    var tmpData = [{
            "name" : "Dell",
            "type" : "business",
            "businessid" : "1",
            "projectid" : "1",
            "submenu" : [{
                    "name" : "OTP",
                    "type" : "product",
                    "productid" : "100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var tmpData1 = [{
            "name" : "Lenovo",
            "type" : "business",
            "businessid" : "1",
            "projectid" : "1",
            "submenu" : [{
                    "name" : "OTP",
                    "type" : "product",
                    "productid" : "100"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
            data : {
                label : 'name',
                items : tmpData
            }
        });

    var treeModel = new dijit.tree.TreeStoreModel({
            store : store,
            query : {
                type : 'business'
            },
            childrenAttrs : ["submenu"]

        });

    var divTestTree = dojo.create("div", null, dojo.body(), "first");
    var mytree = new dijit.Tree({
            model : treeModel
        },
            divTestTree);
    /* Tree is created at this point */

    /* Delete the item from the store,  for some reason tempData is being reset*/
    store.deleteItem(tmpData[0]); 
    /* save */
    store.save();
    /* Tree shows up no more at this point */

    /* Try adding new item to the store */
    store.newItem(tmpData1[0]);
    /* save */
    store.save();
    /*nothing happens! */   
});
```

I followed the lead from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree.html#updating-a-tree), I must be missing something very trivial here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here looking for a solution the problem, 'I suspect there is a bug' is the only answer I got in the forum, so may be this is a bug - goo.gl/M7xg7

Answer (score 0):

Taken from that page

*How do I refresh a Tree from the store?*

*This isn’t supported. The store needs to notify the tree of any changes to the data. Currently this is really only supported (out of the box) by dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore, as setting up a client-server dojo.data source where the server notifies the client whenever the data has changed is quite complicated, and beyond the scope of dojo, which is a client-only solution.*

The only way to update the tree is to re-draw it again :(

Comment: OP is using itemFileWriteStore

Comment: @7dr3am7 - I am using ItemFileWriteStore, the doc is a bit confusing there...according to this doc here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore.html#itemfilewritestore-deletions-reflected-in-dijit-tree  - changes to the store are reflected in the tree, not sure about addItem...

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for a solution the problem, 'I suspect there is a bug' is the only answer I got in the forum, so may be this is a bug - http://goo.gl/M7xg7